# Связи между таблицами MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, таблицы

**Как правильно описать связь между таблицами?**
`supply` - поставка (к примеру, яблоки)
`goods` - что-либо, что было поставлено (те же яблоки)
[image: Связь таблиц]

Таблицы связны *foreign* ключом - `goods_id` с "*NO ACTION*" для случаев добавления или удаления.

Как поступить, если я хочу при добавлении в таблицу `supply` условных яблок с *id = 1* в количестве 10 штук, добавить сразу же эти яблоки в таблицу `goods`?

Первое, что пришло в голову - сделать так:

```
INSERT INTO goods (id, title, amount) VALUES(1, 'apple', 0);
INSERT INTO supply (goods_id, amount) VALUES(1, 10);
UPDATE goods SET amount = 10 WHERE id = 1;
```

**Есть ли более грамотные способы осуществить эту операцию с помощью проработки связей между таблицами?**

Comment: А если будет ещё раз осуществляться поставка яблок, какое значение `amount` должно стать в `goods`? Кумулятивное?

Comment: Использовать триггер? After insert

Comment: @Serodv в этом и проблема, что в таком случае нужно будет получать значение `amount` и уже к нему прибавлять поставку

Comment: В таком случае можно добавить промежуточную таблицу (id поставки, id товара, количество), которая также позволит заказу содержать несколько товаров, а goods будет справочником содержащим id и название.

Comment: @Serodv да, это для осуществления связи "многие ко многим". Меня же интересует как правильно обрабатывать именно случай добавления/удаления поставки. Т.к. интерфейс для БД предполагается как "кнопки добавить и заполняемые поля", для меня является важным именно способ записи\удаления

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это хорошая идея, спасибо. Но является ли это хорошим стилем работы с БД?